# What guarantees that T is one-to-one

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I understand that each column must have a pivot for a transformation to be one-to-one.

I do not understand how the condition "For each $x \in \mathbb R^n$, there is a unique $y \in \mathbb R^m$ so that $T(x) = y$" does not mean that there must be a pivot in every column such that $T$ would be one-to-one.

I thought having a unique output for each input meant that the transformation must be one-to-one

Comment: The output could always be $y=0$. Then $T$ would certainly not be one-to-one.

Comment: A transformation is one-to-one if there is a unique **input** matching corresponding to a given **output**. Your version (where the input/output are switched) is simply the definition of a function.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ohh so by "unique y" the condition just means that only one solution would exist, and not that there is no other x that might also get that y?